# Can creatures abilities target that creature itself?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Spikeshot Goblin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpikeshot%20Goblin%5d) have itself as a target with its ability: "Tap: Spikeshot Goblin deals damage equal to its power to target creature or player"?

Yes or No?

I'm unsure as I read some things like "Rule 114.5. A spell or ability on the stack is an illegal target for itself." But I don't know if that Goblin's ability is on the stack or if it is an ability meant by that rule. Also for me an ability is another thing as a creature - so "itself" would mean the ability is targeting the ability, not "the ability is targeting the Goblin which has that ability".

That's why I ask for a simple answer as Yes or No to the Spikeshot Goblin example above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can Spikeshot Goblin have itself as a target with its ability: "Tap: Spikeshot Goblin deals damage equal to its power to target creature or player"?

Yes. Spikeshot Goblin is a creature, and unless it somehow gains protection from red, shroud, etc. it's a valid target for its own ability.

> 114.5. A spell or ability on the stack is an illegal target for itself.

This only means the ability can't target itself, i.e. *the ability itself*. This is only relevant in rare cases; one example (for spells) would be that you can't change the target of a [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d) on the stack to itself. (If you want to counter a Counterspell with e.g. [Misdirection](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMisdirection%5d), you have to retarget Counterspell to Misdirection; when Counterspell tries to resolve, it will then fizzle because the Misdirection is no longer a valid target, and the original target of Counterspell will not be countered.)

Comment: It might be worth noting that some creatures explicitly exclude themselves as targets for their own abilities, though this is usually only the case with triggered or state-based abilities.